# can not call recognize in TesseractOcr react-native

Tags: react-native, orc

i am doing a feature that is "get text from image" and i used "react-native-tesseract-ocr".
although i read document and followed it but i still get the error. when i print TesseractOcr this is null.
i can not call recognize in TesseractOcr (TesseractOcr.recognize)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2kQn.png)

how can i fix it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrYDL.png)

Comment: please provide code as a text not as an image

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be that you have not linked the package

```
$ react-native link react-native-tesseract-ocr
```

add the import to start

```
import TesseractOcr, { LANG_ENGLISH } from 'react-native-tesseract-ocr';
```

test this finction

```
await TesseractOcr.recognize(imageSource, LANG_ENGLISH, {});
```